# Color all points between 2 x values in matplotlib efficiently

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to color all points in a scatter plot between 2 x values a different color to the rest of the plot. I understand I can do something such as the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(10)

x = np.linspace(1,50,50)
y1 = np.random.rand(50)
y2 = np.random.rand(50)

want_to_color = [20,40]

color_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

c_array1 = []
c_array2 = []
for i in range(50):
    if i > want_to_color[0] and i < want_to_color[1]:
        c_array1.append('r')
        c_array2.append('r')
    else:
        c_array1.append(color_cycle[0])
        c_array2.append(color_cycle[1])

plt.scatter(x, y1, c=c_array1)
plt.scatter(x, y2, c=c_array2)

plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image: Scatter with colored values]

But as you can see, this very memory inefficient, needing a list the size of the data set in order to color all points, when it could simply just be 2 x values. I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

EDIT:

I just thought of a method of doing this using generators, which would be a really nice clean solution. Unfortauntely:

> RuntimeError: matplotlib does not support generators as input

Just because I wrote it anyway, here's the code I tried to use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

col = lambda x, x1, x2, n : map(lambda v: 'r' if v > x1 and v < x2 else plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'][n], x)

np.random.seed(10)

x = np.linspace(1,50,50)
y1 = np.random.rand(50)
y2 = np.random.rand(50)

plt.scatter(x, y1, c=col(x, 20, 40, 0))
plt.scatter(x, y2, c=col(x, 20, 40, 1))

plt.show()
```

NOTE: The code above actually throws the error `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`, but even converting this to the less clean iterable equivalent still doesn't work, as matplotlib simply wont accept generators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more efficient way of creating labels for the scatter plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

np.random.seed(10)

x = np.linspace(1,50,50)
y1 = np.random.rand(50)
y2 = np.random.rand(50)

want_to_color = [20,40]
color_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

c = np.zeros(50)
c[want_to_color[0]+1 : want_to_color[1]] = 1

colors1 = ListedColormap([color_cycle[0], 'r'])
colors2 = ListedColormap([color_cycle[1], 'r'])

plt.scatter(x, y1, c=c, cmap=colors1)
plt.scatter(x, y2, c=c, cmap=colors2)

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

If you prefer not to create an array of labels at all then you can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)

x = np.linspace(1,50,50)
y1 = np.random.rand(50)
y2 = np.random.rand(50)

want_to_color = [20,40]
sl = slice(want_to_color[0]+1, want_to_color[1])
color_cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

plt.scatter(x, y1, c=color_cycle[0])
plt.scatter(x, y2, c=color_cycle[1])
plt.scatter(x[sl], y1[sl], c='r')
plt.scatter(x[sl], y2[sl], c='r')
```

The resulting image is:

[image]